# How to get Android system boot time

Tags: android, shell, time, boot

How can I get the absolute system boot time within the shell?
i tried cat/proc/uptime, but this only returns the time since reboot.

Comment: how is that different ?

Comment: absolute time is the timestamp when the system booted. I want to know this. But uptime just returns the timespan since reboot.

Comment: So substract. Current time - uptime. Any boot, be it reboot counts as a fresh boot for most OSes since they're the ones that have been restarted and they keep track of uptime.

Comment: @A--C put that in as answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's basically:

```
java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() - android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Comment: @fix : Both give time in different frmats.

Comment: But I think it will not give proper result if user has changed a time.

Comment: take into account that the user could change the time and currentTimeMillis() wont be correct, you should fix that by listening to ACTION_TIME_CHANGED http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis() is not affected by timezone, it returns UTC timestamp.

Comment: Except that there is a non-zero amount of time between the two calls.

Comment: That's right. "elapsedRealtimeNanos return the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep. This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing."

Comment: Case1: user changes time from settings according to @keen; Case2: the `System.currentTimeMills()` is not current real time because the stupid rom, I have a device that the system time begin from a specific value every time reboot the system.

Comment: java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() changes when changing the system clock from settings. so the result could be incorrect in this case.